# Database of users with tags

Tags: database, tags

Im fairly new to database design and im trying to work out how the following schema will work.

Id like to have a database of users, which ideally would be in one table. Then for each user I need to store a weighted list of tags, that can be extended later on. For example:

```
User1: dnb (+3), dubstep (+1), classical (-2), rnb (+1)

User2: rnb (+2), hiphop (+4), jazz (-3), classical (-1)
```

Where the bracketed number is the 'weight' of tag for each user. Id like to be able to add more tags to each user at any time as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly simple. You want to represent information about users and tags, with each user having one or more tags and with each tag having a weight. Given that information you have a many-to-many cardinality and you could represent it with three tables:

```
Users(UserID, Name, Surname, DateOfBirth);
Tags(TagID, TagName);
UsersAndTags(UserID, TagID, TagWeight);
```

If you're confused about why this is a many-to-many relationships:

- The user can have one or more tags associated to himself/herself.
- A tag can be associated with many users.

The diagram would look something like this:

- User * ---------------- * Tag

I'll provide a more detailed explanation below.

---

You can represent everything in a relation such as:

```
+--------+------+---------+-------------+-----+-----------+
| UserID | Name | Surname | DateOfBirth | Tag | TagWeight |
+--------+------+---------+-------------+-----+-----------+
```

But this is a bad relation because you are representing heterogeneous information inside a single table and doing so you will end up with inconsistencies. Consider the following (with primary key UserID and Tag):

```
+--------+------+--------------------+-------------+--------+-----------+
| UserID | Name |      Surname       | DateOfBirth |  Tag   | TagWeight |
+--------+------+--------------------+-------------+--------+-----------+
|   1230 | Ana  | Patson             | 12/01/1980  | music  | -1        |
|   2300 | Mike | Johnson            | 01/03/1979  | art    | +3        |
|   2300 | Mike | Johnson            | 01/03/1979  | sports | +1        |
|   2300 | Mike | Johnson            | 01/03/1979  | hiphop | -4        |
|   2300 | Mike | Johnson            | 01/03/1979  | rnb    | -2        |
|   1230 | Ana  | Patson             | 12/01/1980  | rnb    | +1        |
|   1230 | Ana  | Patson             | 12/01/1980  | hiphop | +3        |
|   1230 | Ana  | Patson             | 12/01/1980  | dnb    |  0        |
+--------+------+--------------------+-------------+--------+-----------+
```

We have various inconsistencies in this table, in particular:

- **redundancies**: we have data that is repeated multiple times
- **deletion anomalies**: if we were to delete the fact that user `Ana` with `ID 1230` has no tags associated with herself then we would have to completely remove her from the database since `Tag` is part of our primary key. This is probably not what we want.
- **update anomanies** if Ana gets married and takes the surname of her husband then we have to update all the rows corresponding to her entry multiple times.
- **insert anomalies** we can't insert a new user that has no tag

**Normalization** is a process by which we remove the inconsistencies named above. The most common are: the *the first normal form* (abbreviated 1NF), *second normal form* (2NF), *third normal form* (3NF), *Boyce-Codd normal form* (BCNF). There is also a fourth normal form (and a fifth and a sixth) which I'm not getting into here.

A table is in **first normal form** if all the attributes (i.e. columns) are **atomic**. What this means is that each attribute must represent a single fact and not an aggregation of facts. Our table is in the 1NF.

**Second normal form** deals with composite primary keys (i.e. a primary key with more than one attribute, what we have) and states that a relation is in 2NF if each *other* attribute (i.e. attributes that are not part of the composite primary key) must depend on the ***entire*** primary key. Let's look at our table. At first glance we might think that this relation conforms with 2NF because given the composite primary key `{UserID, Tag}` we can determine all other attributes in the table. However, `Name`, `Surname` and `DateOfBirth` depend only on the `UserID` and not on `Tag` which is part of our composite key as well. Therefor this relation does not conform with `2NF`.

**Third normal form** states that a relation is in 3NF if every attribute in the table depends **directly** on the key. This eliminates the fact that an attribute can depend on another attribute which itself depends on the key (i.e. transitivity rule which is allowed by the 2NF). We already said our table does not conform with 2NF and therefor can't conform with 3NF.

The normal forms are **cumulative**, which means that if our table is in 3NF then it's also in 2NF and 1NF.

These dependencies we've been talking about are called **functional dependencies** (FD). A functional dependency is written like `X -> Y` and you read it as *X functionally determines Y* (or Y is determined by X) and this simply means that the value of X determines the value of Y (where we have the same value for X we must have the same value for Y). In our case whenever we have `UserID` `1230` we have the `Name` `Ana` and `Surname` `Patson` and `DateOfBirth` `12/01/1980`. We therefor have the following functional dependency:

```
UserID -> Name, Surname, DateOfBirth.
```

More formally, 3NF states that for each FD `X -> Y`, X is either the key (or contains a key i.e. a superset of the key) OR *Y is part of the key*. I mentioned this because it's an important fact about 3NF which differentiates it from BCNF. **BCNF** states that for each FD `X -> Y` X is a key.

Other functional dependencies in our relation:

```
UserID, Tag -> TagWeight

UserID, Tag -> All the attributes
```

We can see that the first FD `User -> Name, Surname, DateOfBirth` is not a key (UserID is not the key, only part of the key). This is a problem and this is what's causing anomalies in our relation. When we normalize our relation we decompose based on the functional dependencies. From the first FD we get (R stands for relation i.e. table):

```
R1(UserID, Name, Surname, DateOfBirth)
```

From the second one we get:

```
R2(UserID, Tag, TagWeight)
```

Now it's much better. We represent facts about each user in a different table and facts about users and tag associations in another table. This conforms with 3NF and BCNF.

You might want to add the third table which is the `R3(TagID, Tag)` and replace the `Tag` attribute in `R2` with `TagID` (and you get 3 tables like I said in the beginning).

I haven't touched on lossless-join decomposition which is important and I encourage you to read about. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for all that info. So in this case the table of (UserID, Tag, Weight) would be very long for multiple users and tags (rows = users * their tags)? eg one row user per tag they have?

Comment: You can't have a table where you only have one row for each user with every tag if you want your table to be normalized and without anomalies. I suggest you create it like that (UserID, Tag, Weight) even if the table is large. UserID and Tag is the primary key. Why are you worrying about the number of rows?

Comment: Oh I dont want you to get the wrong end of the stick, I was just clarifying that is the case!